# C# - Preguntar si se quiere cerrar un formulario al presionar el botón de cierre

Tags: c#, windows-forms

En un form tengo codificado un boton para que se pregunte si se quiere cerrar el sistema, si se responde afirmativamente se termina la ejecución del programa, de lo contrario no se hace nada.

Quiero hacer lo mismo para la acción de cerrar el form desde la cruz (arriba a la derecha). Intente llamando al evento click del boton desde el evento form_closing del form, pero da igual si respondo que si o que no, el form se cierra de todas formas.

Es decir, quiero que convivan las dos formas de cerrar el programa, desde la cruz o desde el botón, haciendo la misma pregunta.

Si no se puede hacer eso, otra alternativa que me serviría sería deshabilitar la cruz y que sólo exista el botón (aunque esto lo veo más difícil).

El código del botón es el siguiente:

```
private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mensajes.PreguntaSiNo("¿Está seguro que desea salir del sistema?") == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Y el código del evento form closing es el siguiente:

```
private void frmPrincipal_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        btnSalir.PerformClick();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

se pueden hacer las dos cosas, aunque haciendo desaparecer el botón de cierre (la x de arriba), también van a desaparecer minimizar y maximizar.. así que no es una linda solución..

Lo que tenes que hacer es cancelar el evento cierre una vez que tengas la respuesta de tu botón. Debes usar para eso:

```
FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel = True;
```

dentro del evento FormClosing.

Answer (score 2):

Muchas gracias gbianchi, era más sencillo de lo que suponía. Acá va como quedó el código por si a alguien le sirve:

```
 private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

 private void frmPrincipal_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mensajes.PreguntaSiNo("¿Está seguro que desea salir del sistema?") != DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

private readonly string msg = "Está seguro que desea cerrar esta aplicación?";

```
    private void CloseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult Result;
        Result = MessageBox.Show(msg, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (Result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Explica brevemente qué hace el código: lee [answer].